# Why is my Last-Modified header always sent using GMT timezone?

Tags: html, php, server, http, http-headers

I want to send the last-modified in IST timezone, But it always sends in GMT. What is wrong with this PHP code?

```
echo "Timezone " . date_default_timezone_get () ;  //==>verified, timezone set correctly Asia/Kolkata
$timezone = new DateTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata");
$date =  new DateTime($this->item->modified);
$date->setTimezone($timezone );
$mod_time = trim ($date->format('D, d M Y H:i:s'));
echo $mod_time;
header("Last-Modified: ". $mod_time . " IST", true)  ;
//    header("Last-Modified: ". $mod_time . " IST", true)  ;  //==> Tried this also, still sends in GMT
```

Comment: Is it allowed only GMT ?

Comment: The DateTime constructor takes a second argument of a timezone when creating the date.   Have you tried `$date = new DateTime($this->item->modified, new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));`?   I'm following the example from the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php